# Cause: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "android" (for attribute "enabled")

Tags: android, cordova

Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile resource file: ----------\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\config.xml: . Cause: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "android" (for attribute "enabled")

This is my Cordova Project, I was trying to take a build and getting the above error

I've added this code

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*/application">
<receiver android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</config-file>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Same issue on all of our projects.

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the project `config.xml` root element.

The Cordova project's [config.xml widget element](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/config_ref/#widget) that uses the `android` namespace prefix needs to declare the namespace:

```xml
<widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...> 
    <!-- ... -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*/application">
            <receiver android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent" android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </config-file>
        <!-- ... -->
    </platform>
</widget>
```